# Finding the corresponding sample fraction for a predicted response in classification trees Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tree, scikit-learn, classification, predict

I know how to fit a tree using `sklearn`. I also know how to use it for prediction using either `predict` or `predict_proba`. However, for prediction I want to get the (raw) sample fractions rather than the probability.

For example, in a fitted tree, two leaf nodes might both have probability of 0.2 for class A but one with 2/10 while the other with 400/2000. Now, if I use this tree, I want to get something like [400,2000] or [2,10] rather than just 0.2.

`n_node_sample` and `value` attributes store such information in the fitted tree object but I dont know how to extract the appropriate values from them in prediction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tree's `tree.tree_.apply` method to find out which leaf the point ends up in, and then use the `tree.tree_.value` array to check how many samples of each class are in this leaf:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

iris = load_iris()
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2).fit(iris.data, iris.target)

leaf = tree.tree_.apply(iris.data[50:51].astype(np.float32))
print(leaf)
# output [3]
print(tree.tree_.value[leaf])
# output [[[  0.  49.   5.]]]
print(tree.predict_proba(iris.data[50:51]))
# output [[ 0.          0.90740741  0.09259259]]
```

In the next version 0.17 `tree.tree_.apply` will be "public" as `tree.apply` and will take care of the datatype conversion (to float32). See [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.apply).